# I have R Reproducibility problem peculiar to my my windows 10

Tags: r, windows, random-seed

I run some `R` simulation I wrote before now but gets different results from same version of `R`. I tried such simulation on [a web interface](https://rdrr.io/snippets/) and I got the previous result. What must have changed on my windows 10?

```
set.seed(1)
rnorm(20)

#[1] -0.62645381  0.18364332 -0.83562861  1.59528080  0.32950777 -0.82046838
 #[7]  0.48742905  0.73832471  0.57578135 -0.30538839  1.51178117  0.38984324
#[13] -0.62124058 -2.21469989  1.12493092 -0.04493361 -0.01619026  0.94383621
#[19]  0.82122120  0.59390132
```

as against my new result

```
#[1]  0.46081080  1.34310205  0.99716829 -0.36762421 -0.13198270  1.77709933 -0.46426860 -0.17384681 -0.40401399
#[10]  1.41481488  0.03121604 -1.28415064  0.58393330 -2.06891059  0.12002295 -3.25983598 -0.41697647 -0.51721040
#[19]  0.89266537  1.33231147
```

I triad same on a mobile app called

> R compiler

I got exactly the result

```
#[1] -0.62645381  0.18364332 -0.83562861  1.59528080  0.32950777 -0.82046838
 #[7]  0.48742905  0.73832471  0.57578135 -0.30538839  1.51178117  0.38984324
#[13] -0.62124058 -2.21469989  1.12493092 -0.04493361 -0.01619026  0.94383621
#[19]  0.82122120  0.59390132
```

I now know that my windows 10 has effect on my `R` result.

**My question is what must have changed on my Windows that is affecting my `R` result?**

Comment: Well that's weird! I can conform the one starting with -0.62645381, 0.18364332 ... here.

Comment: Are you loading any other packages? Are you restoring a workspace at startup? What R version is this? Is there any other code at all being run? Do you have anything in your .Rprofile?

Comment: I am using `R` 4.0.3,  it happens either or not I load package like in the case of `rnorm(20)` that I load no package.

Comment: What does `RNGkind()` return for both R versions?

Comment: RNGkind()
[1] "L'Ecuyer-CMRG" "Inversion"     "Rounding"  ###for my Windows 10

Comment: RNGkind()
[1] "LMersenne -Twister"     "Inversion"  ### for my android

Comment: R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.3                         
year           2020                        
month          10           
day            10 
svn rev        79318 
language       R  
version.string R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
nickname       Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read all comments on this question and it greatly inspired me to look inwards. I got

```
file.remove(".RData")
q("no")
```

from [Random Number Generator for R 3.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57874730/random-number-generator-for-r-3-6-1) and it solved my problem